# Parsing the caret position in a rich text box

Tags: vb.net

How do you parse the caret position in a text box, then use that for setting the index in a listbox, all in VB.NET

Comment: it seems like this question was just asked the other day

Comment: It was but i got no answers, no matter how i rephrased it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about a richtextbox, but in a normal textbox you look at the `SelectionStart` property.

**Update** a quick check in Visual Studio confirms the property at least exists for RichTextBox.  You should really start there.

Comment: It does but how would you parse that data?

Comment: There's nothing to parse - it's just an integer property that tells you where the caret is.  Read the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx - that's always a good idea: